# How to fix failure of PHP code in windows:exec(”rm -rf F:/tmpJob/*”)

Tags: apache-2.2, php, windows-xp, permissions

I've installed UnixUtils that's why I can run this kind of commands on windows.

It's executed when browsing a PHP file(http://localhost/filename.php) on windows.

The web server is Apache.

I think it should be divided into 2 steps:

1.found user of Apache threads

2.give enough permissions to that user towards "F:/tmpJob/"

I checked httpd.conf and found:

```
User daemon
Group daemon
```

But there is no "daemon" user on windows.
How to find the **real** user of apache threads?

Answer (score 1):

1 - Look at the properties of the Apache service in the service control manager.  Under the "log on" tab, it should have the user that the service runs as; it's "local system" by default.

2 - I don't know if you'd want to give the local system account that permission; you may want to change the Apache user, and give the new user the permission instead.